# Python Function Calling Within a Function

Tags: python-3.x, function

Having a very simple to fix (I guess at least) issue with calling functions from within another function.
Here's the code:

```
class File_Modification:

    def Start_Up():
        x = 0
        if x == 0:

        print('Options: \n 1. Create New File \n 2. Open Existing File \n 3. Modify Existing File \n 4. Verify File')

        Op_Ans = input()

        if Op_Ans == '1':
            Create_File()
            x = 1

        elif Op_Ans == '2':
            Open_File()
            x = 1

        elif Op_Ans == '3':
            print('Option Three')
            x = 1

        elif Op_Ans == '4':
            print('Option Four')
            x = 1
    Start_Up()
    def Create_File():
        print('Create File Menu')

    def Open_File():
        print('Open File Menu')

    def Modify_File():
        print('Modify File Menu')

    def Verify_File():
        print('Verify File Menu')
```

The code is meant to open a menu, ask the user to input an option and then go to a setting to modify or create information. From the start up function (called once it has been written) the next function i.e. Create_File() gives an error that the function is not recognised.

Any one got any solutions to this error? Haven't been able to find any solutions to this yet.

This is the error I am getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\explo\Downloads\Modify Bulk Files.py", line 1, in 
    class File_Modification:

File "C:\Users\explo\Downloads\Modify Bulk Files.py", line 26, in File_Modification

```
Start_Up()
```

File "C:\Users\explo\Downloads\Modify Bulk Files.py", line 12, in Start_Up
    Create_File()

NameError: name 'Create_File' is not defined

Thanks everyone!

EDIT:

I've made the program work by taking out the class and only using functions. Naming all functions before the StartUp() call. This means it's all created prior.

Thanks everyone for your time. If there's any way of fixing this please note it for future reference. other wise there's my fix.

EDIT 2: Added the error that comes with it and corrected the indentations on the code.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? Right now it is hard to tell what is in the class an what is not.

Comment: Also, please add the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're in a class, so just call them as self.FunctionName()

Comment: Still comes up with the same error just that self isn't determined. Just found a fix around it and that's by taking the class away completely and writing all functions before the StartUp() call. Thanks for the help though mate!

Comment: All good, that's what i was going to suggest but then I saw you had it in a class.